# redis in node.js zadd arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have this line in node.js, but i get wrong number of arguments.
In redis-cli it would be easy, etg test 10 2, but for some reason it wont work here.

example:

```
convensation:convensationIds:user:23984 294874 1
```

my code:

```
 redis_client.zadd(['convensation:convensationIds:user:' + data.from ,convensationId ,data.to]);
```

error:

```
RR wrong number of arguments for 'zadd' command
```

EDIT:

i also tried

```
redis_client.zadd('convensation:convensationIds:user:' + data.from ,convensationId ,data.to);
```

but got the same error as above.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing just one argument, namely an array. Try passing the values of that array as proper arguments:

```
redis_client.zadd('convensation:convensationIds:user:' + data.from ,convensationId ,data.to);
```

Comment: @maria which Redis library are you using? I can't reproduce using [`redis`](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis).

Answer (score 1):

`zadd` takes three parameters:

1. The first is the name of the Z set
2. The second is number, most probably 0
3. The third is new value

Example:
`client.zadd("job", 0  , string_job);`